# Bitbucket API 2 - create repository in a team project

Tags: bitbucket-api

I have a team on my bitbucket account, `myteam`, which contains a project named `mainproject`. Whenever I want to create a repository inside I only need to execute this command line:

```
$ curl -X POST -v -u myaccount:passwd "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myteam/repo1" -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks"}'
```

This works. However the issue arises when I create a second project, named `secondproject`. How am I supposed to tell the API to which project the repository should belong?

I tried specifying the project information in the data (-d):

```
$ curl -X POST -v -u myaccount:passwd "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myteam/repo2" -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks", "project": {"name": "secondproject"} }'
```

or with the key parameter:

```
$ curl -X POST -v -u myaccount:passwd "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myteam/repo2" -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks", "project": {"key": "SEC"} }'
```

This will create the repository repo2 in the project `mainproject`.

I tried using the uuid but the same occurs, repo is created in the mainproject.

I tried putting the project name in the link:

```
$ curl -X POST -v -u myaccount:passwd "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myteam/secondproject/repo1" -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks"

...
{"error": {"message": "Resource not found", "detail": "There is no API hosted at this URL.\n\nFor information about our API's, please refer to the documentation at: https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/IYBGDQ"}}
```

How can I specify which project the repository I want to create belongs to?
I am not looking for a GUI solution, I want to stick to the command line as I need to automatize the creation of repositories this way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The content type has to be specified to `curl` with this argument: `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`. Then the `json` data would be accessed normally. So the final command would look like this:

```
$ curl -X POST -v -u myaccount:passwd "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myteam/repo2" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"has_wiki": true, "is_private": true, "project": {"key": "PRJ_KEY"}}'
```

Comment: Is there any way to script this without writing/prompt a password? Using SSH for example?

Comment: It should be noted that the TEAM in the url is case-sensitive...in this case 'myteam'. In my case we had some uppercase letters in that name, and we did NOT get a friendly error when it failed.

Comment: I tried that I got  `* Connection #0 to host api.bitbucket.org left intact
{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Forbidden"}}`

Comment: Docs are at https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#post