# Git - Create a new repository for each folder in a directory

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Very new to git, so please bear with me. Using Bitbucket/Sourcetree if that matters.

We have some code not currently in source control anywhere.
For lack of a better term, let's think of them as Java projects.
Each project is in its own folder in a directory.
We have dozens of projects.

Is there an easy way to create a new repository for each project/folder and push it up to Bitbucket without doing it one by one?

I feel like I shouldn't make the root folder a repository since multiple projects would be checked out simultaneously and it would be confusing from a commit/push/deploy to the master branch perspective.

Again, I'm new to git, so maybe I'm not thinking of this correctly.

Comment: Is it so bad doing it manually? You only need to do it once...

Comment: I agree with Mason! Automate it with a (simple) script using some git terminal commands. I have done it onec to create pull request and stuff. Have you seen this? I guess it could help: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/automate-project-github-setup-mac/

Comment: I'm guessing this is done with the git command line?  I've never programmed or run anything with linux but I can struggle through it with the examples you guys posted.  Thanks for the help!  I'll check back if I get hung up.

Answer (score 1):

That should be managed by a script, which could:

- do a `git init` in each Java project folder
- add, commit
- `git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/me/<newProjectW`
- and also: create the new remote repository directly from the same script.

See "[Create repo on Bitbucket programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65872400/6309)"

```sh
curl -X POST --user 'user:app_pass'  \ 
    -H "Content-type: application/json" \
    -d '{"project":{"key":"PROJ"}}'     \
   "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/USER/REPO"
```

- finally: `git push -u origin main`

That way, in one script, you do everything.

Comment: Thanks.  Where do you run this?  git command line or windows command line?  I've never used curl.

Comment: @mang All those steps, including curl, can be executed from a bash script (which runs even on Windows, considering bash is included in Git for Windows).